# Using the Android TV platform on a device that is not an "Android TV device"

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tv, android-compatibility

I am developing an app for an Android device running Android L 5.1.1 that will be hooked on TVs.

The device however is not an "Android TV" device.

My question is: **can I still leverage the "Android TV" platform, for example to handle TV hardware (remote, gamepad) and 10-foot UI?**

Maybe by using a compatibility library? or are those features strictly limited to compatible devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing it out:

**Yes, you can run an app using the Android TV platform on a device which is not an "Android TV" device.**